# switch case arguments in c

Tags: c, switch-statement

This may look simple but I am not able to find the syntax to use the switch case statement. I want to give the command as below in command line:

```
dumpFile -t TYPE -c Filename
dumpFile -c Filename
```

In both the cases I need '-c' option to work in different manner.Like in first case, I am checking the type first and the using '-c' option. In latter I am not checking any type and performing some different operation.

I want to know the switch case which will work for both. Like in only '-c' option the argument is argv[2] whereas in former('t' and 'c' both) the argv is 4 :argv[4].What I tried only work for ('-t' and '-c' together) but cannot find any way how to use second switch case(with only 'c')

```
Code:

while ((i = getopt(argc, argv, "tc:o")) != EOF) {
    switch (i){
case 't':
    if(strcmp(argv[2],"SomeType") == 0){
       fprintf(stdout, "type matched\n");
    }
    break;
case 'c':
    open_f(argv[4], hBuf);
    if(strcmp(hBuf, "8000") == 0 && strcmp(argv[2], "someType") == 0){
       fprintf(stdout, "Command:..");

       // If I use argv[2] here, upper part will also execute which I don't want in second command
       // do some stuff
    break;
case 'o':
case default:
    ...
```

Comment: Use optarg instead of argv[4]...

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can know how you are checking the number of command line arguments, etc.

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: if(strcmp(argv[2],"SomeType") == 0){ This is making a VERY IFFY assumption on the order of the command line parameters. That is NOT how to use getopt() when a (-) option is presented that has a following value.   Rather, the char* `optarg` will point to the argument for the current option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why `getopt` sets the variable `optarg`.  See [the documentation for `getopt`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt).

Also, any flag that requires an argument is supposed to be immediately followed by a colon, not just somewhere later in the list.

A working example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "t:c:o")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 't':
            printf("type: %s\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'c':
            printf("command: %s\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'o':
            printf("other\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want both commands to output different results. How using optarg differentiate between ('-t' and '-c' together) and only (-c) option?

Comment: @Karan Set variables so your program remembers if it's seen each option.

Comment: this posted answer does not handle the scenario(s) defined by the OP

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `optarg` as shown [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/getopt.html)

> The getopt() function returns the next option character (if one is found) from argv that matches a character in optstring, if there is one that matches. If the option takes an argument, getopt() sets the variable optarg to point to the option-argument as follows:
>
> If the option was the last character in the string pointed to by an element of argv, then optarg contains the next element of argv, and optind is incremented by 2. If the resulting value of optind is not less than argc, this indicates a missing option-argument, and getopt() returns an error indication.
>
> Otherwise, optarg points to the string following the option character in that element of argv, and optind is incremented by 1.

Comment: please don't post a 'link only Answer' but quote the relevant part

Comment: A mere link to external documentation should be posted as a comment, not an answer. By policy, answers should provide something unique to SO. That being said, I don't think `getopt` is the right tool to use here in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

> In both the cases I need '-c' option to work in different manner.Like in first case,

Using one option to mean two different things seems like poor design. It means that users will have to remember not only the several meanings of the option, but also how to trigger the one they want.

> I want to know the switch case which will work for both.

It seems like you're trying to do too much in one place. You'll probably be better off if you just process the arguments to the command, including options, first, and then figure out how the program should behave. For example, if you see a `-c` option in the argument list, just set a variable that indicates that that option is set.

> I am not able to find the syntax to use the switch case statement.

You've got the syntax for `switch` down fine; the problem is that you're trying to implement some convoluted logic, and you're using the wrong tool to do it. Figure out what arguments you got first, and then use that information to determine the behavior of the program. Also, if the order of the options is important, `switch` might not be the right way to go. You seem to expect a specific order since you're using exact indexes into `argv`:

> if(strcmp(argv[2],"SomeType") == 0){

But the cases in your switch could come in any order. What will you do if you get called like this?

```
> dumpfige -c -t TYPE Filename
```

Comment: Thanks!. That is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`getopt` is probably too blunt for your needs. You could replace it with manual parsing:

- Check `argc` and make sure there are arguments to begin with.
- Loop `for(size_t i=1; i<argc; i++)`, where you skip index 0.

  - Check that the `strlen(argv[i])` is >= 2. If not, error and exit.
  - Check that `argv[i][0]` is `-`. If not, error and exit.
  - `switch` on `argv[i][1]`.